# AC single pin male/female plug

Tags: ac, connector

Is there any single pin AC male/female plug available? What is it called? I tried  searching on google but didn't find anything.

I am looking something similar to an RCA cable for transmitting AC signal (only type from each cable i.e. ground/live/neutral)

**edit:**  I found a nice [video for AC connectors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMEy0wHYT_c). The video explains different kinds of available AC connectors.

Comment: RCA cables do transmit AC signals?  If you want a single wire and don't care about interference you could just use a, you know, a wire.

Comment: @codesnooker  Why do you need an unusual connector like that?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NickAlexeev want to give a nicer look to my home automation project.

Comment: @crgrace  The problem with re-purposing RCA (or any other common household connector) is that somebody may plug a speaker into it.  The speaker will be fried, and it may also  catch fire.  This connector should be either standard for mains AC, or it should be unique, or it should be inaccessible to innocent bystanders.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Actually it will hidden behind the board. I am looking something very easy that can be used for demo purpose without need of electrical tapes and other mess. Upon more research, I think, Wire Nut and Push Wire connectors seems good option to me. Let me check the availability at local store

Comment: Why not just a screw terminal?  There isn't any risk of somebody plugging something in since the screw terminal isn't used as a standard connector for anything.  They are extremely common as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is an Anderson Power Pole single-pin connector. These are a hermaphrodite 30 Amp single-pin connector that can be ganged together to make a connector that has as many pins as you want.

They are commonly seen in stage-lighting dimmer racks to patch the pins on the multi-pin Socapex connectors to the specific dimmer channel desired.

They are massively reliable and relatively inexpensive.

You can see them [here](http://www.andersonpower.com/products/singlepole-connectors.html).  According to that page, the small ones are good for up to 45 Amps and all are rated for 600 Vac operation.  They are UL listed and I know that I've seen them with CSA markings as well.

I really like these connectors - I've been using Power Pole connectors for decades and have always had great results with them.  You will often see the larger double-pin connectors used in electric fork lifts for the battery connections.

[EDIT]

I just realized that you didn't specify what voltage and current you wanted.

There are large single-pin connectors available that are used for temporary AC power distribution panels. These go by the names "Camlock" & "Tweeco" and are available in current rating up to 200 Amps or more.

Have a chat with your local electricians about those if you need something that large.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got a nice video for AC Connectors. Video explain different kind of available AC connectors https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMEy0wHYT_c

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for 250V 10Amp AC. I find Wire Nut and Push Wire Connector are cheaper and easier option for local electrician.